# Set default value with grouped_options_for_select , using f.select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a grouped drop down menu rendered by the following,

```
= f.select :location_id, 
           grouped_options_for_select(grouped_location_options, 
                                      default_location_name), 
           { selected: default_location_name }, 
           class: 'form-control'
```

I would like to have the **default value** to be **Unassigned**, but the above code doesn't seem to be doing what I'd like.

Could someone give me some clues to solve this??

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give group option in any of below format:

```
    grouped_options = {
          'North America' => [['United States','US'], 'Canada'],
          'Europe' => ['Denmark','Germany','France']
        }
```

**OR**

```
 grouped_options = [
   ['North America', [['United States','US'],'Canada']],
   ['Europe',['Denmark','Germany','France']]
 ]
```

To select Us and Denmak use below code:

```
grouped_options_for_select(grouped_options, ['US', 'Denmark'])
```

**Update:**

```
grouped_options = {
      'Unassigned' => [['Unassigned','1']],
      'Assigned' => [['Trainer 1 Location', 3], ['Trainer 5 Location', 4]] 
    }
```

to select Unassigned use : `grouped_options_for_select(grouped_options, ['1'])`

to select assigned by default pass id of unassigned in `grouped_option_from_select`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @rahul!

I'm pulling data from the DB, however, and one of the locations being fetched is 'Unassigned', so I'd like to have the default value for the dropdown menu set to 'Unassigned'.

Comment: could you please paste your grouped_location_options value

Comment: Okay, so the code I'm using to set the *grouped_locations* variable is the following:

    unassigned_location = current_locations.location.where(name: 'Unassigned)
    unassigned_location.map { |loc| [loc.name, loc.id] }

    assigned_locations = current_locations.location.where.not(name: 'Unassigned')
    assigned_locations = assigned_locations.map { |loc| [loc.name, loc.id] }

With the above expressions, the respective locations can be fetched from the DB based on their respective Id's

Comment: please paste the value of assigned_locations and unassigned_location

Comment: Oops, sorry...

Okay,

*assigned_locations = [['Trainer 1 Location', 3], ['Trainer 5 Location', 4]]*, *unassigned_locations = [['Unassigned', 1]]*

Comment: Great, thanks, @rahul!  I'll test this out and do some experimenting!

Comment: I've got some other important tasks to attend to ATM, but I'll test this out in the afternoon.

Comment: Bingo!  Had to modify a bit, of course, but works smoothly!
Many thanks.